# Downloading file from url hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I have 300+ hyperlinks listed on an Excel worksheet.

I want to download everything from each link to my computer.

This code is not downloading the Excel file or the pdf file on the link.

```
Sub test()

Dim hlink As Hyperlink
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveloc As String

saveloc = "C:\Users\"
For Each hlink In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Hyperlinks
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(hlink.Address)
    wb.SaveAs saveloc & hlink.Parent & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

and this code

```
Sub DownloadFile()
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Dim oStream As Object
Dim myURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String

myURL = "https://"
LocalFilePath = "C:\Users"

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "", ""  '("username", "password")
WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile LocalFilePath, 2
    oStream.Close
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also used this code Sub test()

Dim hlink As Hyperlink
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveloc As String

saveloc = "C:\Users\"
For Each hlink In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Hyperlinks
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(hlink.Address)
    wb.SaveAs saveloc & hlink.Parent & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing
Next

End Sub

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: it just makes an empty excel doc with the name of the link as the name

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2328-excel-open-multiple-hyperlinks.html

VBA code: Open multiple hyperlinks at once

Copy and Run:

```vb
Sub OpenHyperLinks()
'Update 20141124
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted to `DownloadFile()` can't work because right now it only calls `https://` as an URL and nothing else.

As you haven't provided more information I would suggest that you combine your two methods to actually use URL's given in your excel

```
Sub DownloadFile()
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Dim oStream As Object
Dim myURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String
For Each hlink In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Hyperlinks
myURL = hlink 
LocalFilePath = "C:\Users"

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "", ""  
WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile LocalFilePath + someFileName, 2 'you have to create a unique filename here (maybe split the hlink for something usefull)
    oStream.Close
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I deleted the web address I wanted to download from for privacy reasons. On excel i have used a full URL address.